# Understanding coordinates arguments in `geom_path` and similar functions

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am starting from a simple barplot:

```
df <- data.frame(xpos=c(200,300,400),
                 ypos=c(  1,  3,  2))
gp <- ggplot(df, aes(x=xpos, y=ypos)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

and then want to add custom multiline given the coordinates of its points (let's say these coordinates are totally custom and not related to barplot data). It works well with 3 points:

```
gp + geom_path(mapping=aes(x=c(200, 200, 300), 
                           y=c(1.5,   2,   2)), 
               size=1.2)
```

*(here was a question about `mapping` vs `data` but I got it now thanks to David's comment. I should have rather put these two questions separately, sorry for the mess)*

Then, if I try to add one or two more points, this doesn't work anymore:

```
gp + geom_path(mapping=aes(x=c(200, 200, 300, 300), 
                           y=c(1.5,   2,   2,  1)), 
               size=1.2)
# Error in data.frame(x = c(200, 200, 300, 300), y = c(1.5, 2, 2, 1), PANEL = c(1L,  : 
# arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 3
```

why does it cut my data to 3? same with 5 points, but ok again with 6:

```
gp + geom_path(mapping=aes(x=c(200, 200, 300, 300, 100, 150), 
                           y=c(1.5,   2,   2,  1,  1.5, 1.8)), 
               size=1.2)
```

I thought that `geom_path` simply connects all the coordinates, so we only need to provide equal number of `x` and `y` arguments. Why in my case it works only in groups of 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem is related to that you have put the three-row data frame in the 'top level' in `ggplot`. When the number of points in the `geom_path` data then is not a multiple of the number of rows in the data frame (e.g. 4 vs 3) the error occurs, because at some point `ggplot` tries to combine the data to one data frame.

One possible work-around is to move the data for `geom_bar` from `ggplot` to `geom_bar`:

```
gp <- ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = df, aes(x = xpos, y = ypos), stat = "identity") +
  geom_path(mapping = aes(x = c(200, 200, 300, 300),
                          y = c(1.5,   2,   2,  1)))              
gp
```

If you look at the data which is used to render the plot, you see that it is in two separate data frames:

```
str(ggplot_build(gp)$data)
# List of 2
# $ :'data.frame':  3 obs. of  8 variables: <~~ this is the data for the bars
# ..$ x    : num [1:3] 200 300 400
# ..$ y    : num [1:3] 1 3 2
# ..$ PANEL: int [1:3] 1 1 1
# ..$ group: int [1:3] 1 1 1
# ..$ ymin : num [1:3] 0 0 0
# ..$ ymax : num [1:3] 1 3 2
# ..$ xmin : num [1:3] 155 255 355
# ..$ xmax : num [1:3] 245 345 445
# $ :'data.frame':  4 obs. of  4 variables: <~~ this is the data for the path
#   ..$ x    : num [1:4] 200 200 300 300
# ..$ y    : num [1:4] 1.5 2 2 1
# ..$ PANEL: num [1:4] 1 1 1 1
# ..$ group: int [1:4] 1 1 1 1
```

This is the case also when you use your first attempt, with "df" in the top level, and the number of points in `geom_path` being a multiple of the number of rows in "df". Thus, with "df" in the top level,`ggplot` tries at some point to combine the data to one data frame, and then renders the plot with separate data frames for each layer.

```
gp <- ggplot(df, aes(x = xpos, y = ypos)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_path(mapping = aes(x = c(200, 200, 300, 300, 100, 150),
                          y = c(1.5,   2,   2,  1,  1.5, 1.8)))
str(ggplot_build(gp)$data)
```

This highlights a general characteristic of `ggplot`: it is very data frame-centered.

Comment: thanks for explanation, I came more or less to the same point; another work-around I found is to put coordinates to `data=`.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake: without overriding `data`, our `mapping` uses dimensions of original dataframe. So, in my case, I need to explicitly put the coordinates of my path in `data`.